# Login error in desktop application using Facebook Developer Toolkit

Tags: .net, desktop-application, facebook-login

I'am developing .NET desktop application using Facebook Developer Toolkit from http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/39727. Everything worked fine until end of previous month. Login to Facebook stopped working. After you enter credentials and hit the login button, System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException is raised inside API I'am using:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at Facebook.Session.DesktopSession.CompleteLogin(Dictionary`2 sessionProperties)
at Facebook.Session.DesktopSession.Login()
at Facebook.Winforms.Components.FacebookService.ConnectToFacebook(List`1 permissions)
```

To me, it looks like there were some changes in Facebook API, maybe in some URL, whose parts are used as keys for dictionary. I'am desperate, because I invested huge amount of time for developing that desktop application. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to create new testing application in App Center and use its App ID in my desktop application. Now following error is shown in login window:  
API Error Code: 100  
API Error Description: Invalid parameter  
Error Message: Please migrate to OAuth2 and use new /dialog/oauth endpoint. return_session is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library is now deprecated and not developing anymore, so there is need to find better one.